# Set EDT emulation by default for Emacs

Tags: configuration, emacs

Using the [Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) editor I can set it to enable [OpenVMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS) [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDT_%28text_editor%29) editor keypad mode with this command:

```
M-x edt-emulation-on
```

How can I set it so that whenever I invoke Emacs, EDT emulation is the default on a  Linux system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [emacs edt](https://idlebox.net/2011/apidocs/emacs-23.3.zip/edt/edt_3.html) documentation:

```
(add-hook 'term-setup-hook 'edt-emulation-on)
```

For `term-setup-hook` have a look at the [emacs documentation about terminal initialization](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Terminal-Init.html).

Comment: The "emacs edt" document is missing the first quote mark.